# How to predict non negative values of a target in xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting

I am using `xgboost` (in R) to predict a continuous non-negative target variable using standard root mean squared error as an evaluation metric (and loss function). However, as pointed out in [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/565/why-does-gradient-boosting-regression-predict-negative-values-when-there-are-no), it is possible that a non-negative target sometimes receives negative predictions. Since I have many training values in the target that are close to zero, there are a few observations that have received a prediction below zero.

So, is there any way to train my `xgboost` model so that predictions are >= 0? Maybe through different loss functions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from the obvious: "*transform the response data such that we model the log of them and back-transform them to get the final non-negative estimates*", we can always set our modelling objective as `reg:gamma` or `reg:tweddie` and ensure the non-negativity of the predicted results. And if our modelling target is counts we can use `count:poisson` too. All these options can be found in the  [XGBoost Parameters](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) page.